# Missing "transferred kbytes" in TortoiseSVN update or checkout dialog

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

In former times, with older versions of TortoiseSVN (I think at least TortoiseSVN 1.6.x), I got the feedback how many kbytes or mbytes were transferred when using the checkout or update dialog in TortoiseSVN.

Nowadays (with TortoiseSVN 1.8.x), this information is just missing. When I do a checkout, I see during the checkout the information flying through `Transferring at x kbytes/sec`, but at the end, I only get: `Added: x`

[image]   [image]

Why is that information not any more visible? Is there a way to see it again?

Comment: Stefan Kung answered this here: http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=757&dsMessageId=3123264

Comment: How about earning some "reputation"? I will give the answer explicitly, so the readers may find it here ...

Comment: just mark your answer as accepted! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what the author of `TortoiseSVN`, Stephan Küng has answered in the [forum question](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=757&dsMessageId=3123275):

> As for why it was removed: I got tired of explaining why the total 
>   amount of transferred data didn't match with what users expected. And 
>   since it rarely matched the expectations, why even show it?
>
> Reasons for why it doesn't match:
>   the total bytes transferred include authentication data (can be a *lot* 
>   when authenticating against a domain), the data can be compressed, only 
>   changes are sent/received and not whole files, ...

So that explains in details why it was changed (but I liked the additional information I got).